# hibernate 6 fetching to much at once

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-6.x

I have some big entities with lots of columns and selfreferences. Somthing like this:

```
@Entity public class Person{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String title;
    .... 50 more columns ....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
      @JoinColumn(name = "k1", rerencedColumnName = "k1"),
      @JoinColumn(name = "k2", referencedColumnName = "k2") })
    private Person representation;
}
@Entity public class Assignment{
   @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(...)
   private Person leader;
   @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(...)
   private Person employee;
}
```

That usually worked. But ever since upgrading to Hibernate6 all these columns and manyToOnes are joinfetched which frequently results in:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error advancing (next) ResultSet position
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
SqlExceptionHelper.java:109
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
SqlExceptionHelper.java:95
    ... 201 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Eine Zeile der Größe 9020 kann nicht erstellt werden, da sie länger als die zulässige maximale Zeilengröße von 8060 wäre.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerException.java:262
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet$FetchBuffer.nextRow(SQLServerResultSet.java:5415) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerResultSet.java:5415
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.fetchBufferNext(SQLServerResultSet.java:1758) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerResultSet.java:1758
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.next(SQLServerResultSet.java:1016) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
SQLServerResultSet.java:1016
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.next(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.lambda$processNext$0(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar:6.1.5.Final]
```

I don't quite get why the exceptionmessage is in german but it says `a row of the size 9020 can't be created since it is bigger than the maximum allowed size of 8000`

Comment: Ah Hibernate. With each major upgrade you learn new ways in which you were always using it wrong but until then they had code in place to sweep mistakes under the rug. The meaty part you cut out in that ... 50 more rows... bit since if this is to do with manyToOnes, it would be prudent to show how you declare them.

Comment: Wow you are really feeling my pain . I updated my post to show the way I usually declare my manyToOnes. Hope this helps. Looking at the hql directly i can seen at least 30 joins. I think in lower versions they used more subselects.

Comment: And any OneToMany? ManyToMany?

Comment: Nope. I avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: You might want to add some lazy fetch types to those manyToOnes, they are eager fetched by default.